# Why do we use "its" for possessive?

Tags: pronouns, possessives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't “its” have an apostrophe?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22603/why-doesnt-its-have-an-apostrophe)

Generally, there is an apostrophe when someone possesses something:

> That's Gerald's cat.
>
> Gerald's cat is dead.

But when it comes to the possessive of *it*, *its* is correct, and not *it's*.

> The common house cat is endeared for *its* ability to land on *its* feet.

Why is this? If *Gerald's* is correct, why is *it's* not correct?

Comment: maybe this is enough: http://the-editor.uphero.com/2011/02/24/its-or-its/

Comment: @Unreason: I see they give the example *The dog's bark is worse than its bite* on that link. To which I would add **so it's its bark you should fear**.

Comment: I swear I searched for a duplicate before this, and somehow didn't find it... Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of "its" as going with "his" or "hers" - you don't use an apostrophe in those even though they are possessive.

Comment: And, to give the other half of the answer, "it's" is completely unrelated and is the contraction for "it is".

Comment: @David alternatively it's from the middle English 'es' possesive and marks the missing 'e'

Comment: Actually, *it's* is the original form of the possessive. The apostrophe got dropped only recently. (Like, last century recently.)

Answer (score 2):

There are two primary reasons

1. Possesive pronouns do not end with 's (mine, yours, hers/his, ours, theirs)
2. Ambiguity. "It's" is a contraction of "it is". In most cases, substituting "it is" for "its" in a sentence would result in nonsense, but I'm sure there are cases where it could still make sense, therefore changing the meaning. Either way it would be incorrect.