# When did it become incorrect to use apostrophes with possessive pronouns?

Tags: orthography, pronouns, history, possessives

I'm reading Jane Austen's *Sense and Sensibility*, and I notice that she invariably uses an apostrophe with possessive pronouns — in a way that would be considered incorrect now. For example: (Elinor is speaking to Colonel Brandon)

> *My* gratitude will be insured immediately by any information tending to that end, and *her's* must be gained by it in time. Pray, pray let me hear it. (Volume II, Chapter IX, page 153 of the Oxford World's Classics edition, emphases in original)

Assuming that Austen is a reasonably good yardstick for proper style *of her time*, I'm wondering *when* this practice came to be considered incorrect. (Note that there are some related questions, especially [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95853/where-did-the-practice-of-using-apostrophes-for-possessive-nouns-but-not-pronoun). But that question's answers don't get into any real detail about the *when* part of the question.)

**Edit**: @FumbleFingers points out in the comments that my example may be a bad one. In the original, the sentence would have had "HERS" (and no apostrophe). My larger point stands, and here are a few other examples without that problem:

> When they stopped at the door, Mrs. Jennings recollected that there was a lady at the other end of the street on whom she ought to call; and as she had no business at Gray's, it was resolved, that while her young friends transacted their's, she should pay her visit and return for them. (Chapter 33)
>
> But at last she found herself with some surprise, accosted by Miss Steele, who, though looking rather shy, expressed great satisfaction in meeting them, and on receiving encouragement from the particular kindness of Mrs. Jennings, left her own party for a short time, to join their's. (Chapter 38)
>
> That conviction must be every thing to you; and he is undoubtedly supported by the same trust in your's. (Chapter 24)

Those examples are all taken from the [Gutenberg edition online](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/161/161-h/161-h.htm).

**Edit after closing**: It's funny that this should be closed so soon after the blog post about [The War of the Closes](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes). The alleged duplicate does not talk about my question, namely *when* did good usage shift forms like *her's*, *their's*, etc. to *hers*, *theirs*, etc. Nor does the only answer to that question address the *when* question. That other question and its answer are about whether forms like *hers* came to exist by analogy with the possessive of nouns, such as *John's*. It's a completely different question. In addition, this question now has a reasonably good answer. There's no reason for this to be closed.

Comment: That's a peculiarity of the particular copy you happen to be reading. The vast majority of contemporary editions would modernise the typography anyway. In which context I think it's extremely likely that Austen herself used capitals to emphasise MY and HERS, rather than switching to an *italic font*. So your OWC edition seems to have been a bit idiosyncratic in keeping the totally unacceptable apostrophe, but unnecessarily changing the font.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I grant you that many editions would regularize the apostrophes away. I also grant, since I have no information one way or the other, that the italics may be a choice of my editor (James Kinley). However, I think it's very unlikely that this edition would have *added* apostrophes, so I assume that they are Austen's. In which case, my original question stands: Was that apostrophe really so "unacceptable" in her time?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: It's in the public domain, so there are lots of instances in Google Books of [by any information tending to that end](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22by+any+information+tending+to+that+end%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) - which are almost all reproductions of exactly this Austen sentence. Most of them use capitals, not italics.

Comment: I never knew that capital letters were used in literature for emphasis. And we moan when people write in caps nowadays!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I added some other examples to remove the distraction over italics versus caps. (It's interesting, but not directly relevant to my real question.)

Comment: I'm not sure there's anything more to say than was posted by [this earlier answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/68653/2637). *"**Its** is just as possessive as **cat's**, but it doesn't have an apostrophe. Why not? Because [C19] printers and grammarians **never thought the matter through***. Austen (or a later printer, or even **hers** :) was just following a relatively short-lived (and inconsistent) typography convention that was never likely to last *because of* the inconsistencies.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's a reasonable answer, as far as it goes, but who's to say that someone might not have more detailed information about *when* these conventions shifted so completely away from the apostrophe? That quotation is just one book, after all.

Comment: @ Telemachus: As [this chart shows](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=her%27s%2Ctheir%27s&year_start=1700&year_end=1900&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), the "apostrophised" usage peaked in the late 1700s. But it was always illogical and inconsistent (what about **his**, and **it's = it is**, for example?). I think it was bound to fall away as more people noticed the problems, but there's no-one "in charge" of such matters - so I can't see how you could meaningfully look for a detailed history of how, when, and why the convention got quietly dropped over many decades.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I didn't ask for "a detailed history of how, when and why". I'm happy to accept something as general as "that usage peaked in the late 1700s" if there's no better answer. But I still wonder if there isn't something more to be said. How about if we see whether anyone else comes up with anything before deciding that the question can't be answered? Also note [The Grammar of English Grammars](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/11615/pg11615.html) (circa 1850) for some disagreements among grammarians.

Comment: Have a look at the "history" section in Wikipedia's page for [English possessive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_possessive). Particularly, note that, for example, *St James's Park* was sometimes written as *St James **his** Park*, back in C16. That was never "justified", but it just goes to show how fickle typographic conventions can be.

Comment: I've come across the "X his Y" idiom before as well. (For example a treatise called [Solon His Follie](http://www.acmrs.org/publications/catalog/richard-beacon-solon-his-follie). But what you're calling a "fickle typographic convention" strikes me more as a case of the language working out how to express something and becoming more standardized.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you've inadvertantly stumbled over the origin of 's - it's a contraction of X his Y -> X's Y.

Comment: @TheMathemagician: Not so. Per Wikipedia's "history" section in that previous link, *The **'s** morpheme originated in Old English as an inflexional suffix marking genitive case.* It goes on to dismiss *X **his** Y* as an erroneous "folk etymology".

Comment: Welcome to the site, and good question! I can't wait to hear the answer/explanation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks I was unaware of that. The person who told me 's was derived from his read English at Cambridge so should've known better. However they've been dead for 20 years so I can't really berate them.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't think this question is really a duplicate of that one. I'm not asking about the origin of the pronouns. I'm asking about the history of a change. Neither the question nor the (only) answer to it say anything about forms like *her's*, *your's* or *their's*.

Comment: Maybe it's not exactly a duplicate of the one Mari-Lou posted, but I still think [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/68653/2637) to *Why doesn't “its” have an apostrophe?* pretty much covers it. Austen was writing when the (ultimately, doomed) [fad for **her's**](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=her%27s&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) was quite widespread. But it was [never dominant](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=her%27s%2Chers&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: This question is based on a false premise that at any given time there's a definitive set of rules governing what is or isn't correct orthography. Clearly we all have no hesitation in saying **her's** is "incorrect" today, but 2-3 centuries ago it was at least "acceptable" to some (always, the minority).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since *your's* and *her's* are virtually always incorrect in modern English, one way to answer your question is to look at the frequency of those terms in published books.

Searching Google Ngram Viewer for [*your's* and *her's*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=your%27s%2Cher%27s&year_start=1700&year_end=1900&corpus=15&smoothing=3) shows the terms peaking in popularity around Jane Austen's lifetime and virtually extinct by 1850.

[image: Ngram]