# Why should "theirs" not have an apostrophe?

Tags: pronouns, history, apostrophe, possessive-pronouns

What is the reasoning by which people decided not to use *’s* to indicate the possession of pronouns?

For example, one might write

- It is Jack's dog.
- The dog is Jack's.

But not

- It is their dog.
- The dog is their's.

Why does using a pronoun not follow the same *apostrophe-s* pattern as used for the noun it replaces?

Comment: Hello, user382881. Please edit your question to include 1. an example of at least one sentence where people did not use **'s**, and 2. the reason why you think it should be used.

Comment: @Conrado (1) is trivial because *theirs* is correct standard English. (2) is simply "it follows the same pattern."

Comment: I suspect that the suggested "related question" about [it's/its](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22603/why-doesnt-its-have-an-apostrophe) is relevant.

Comment: Thank you, @Andrew Leach. Still, an example like the one user382881 included now helps to clarify the reason for the question and OP's initial data.